# Central Directory Corrupt deploying Python Azure function

Tags: python, azure, function, deployment

I was previously able to deploy an Azure function written in Python using the command `func azure functionapp publish <FunctionAppName>`  from my project directory, building it remotely.  It worked until lunchtime yesterday.

I now get the following message.

```
Creating archive for current directory...
Performing remote build for functions project.
Deleting the old .python_packages directory
Uploading  [######################################################################################]
Remote build in progress, please wait...
Fetching changes.
Cleaning up temp folders from previous zip deployments and extracting pushed zip file /tmp/zipdeploy/c5e66350-4b87-4e72-9900-b2a1ae4521a8.zip (0.00 MB) to /tmp/zipdeploy/extracted
Central Directory corrupt.
Remote build failed!
```

I've tried the following to see if I can resolve it without any success:

- Switching my machine off and on.
- Deploying an older version of the code in case I've changed anything.
- Deploying from the command prompt in visual studio code.
- Reinstalling Azure functions core tools.
- Deploying from a different machine on a different network (I read that there are sometimes firewall issues with uploading zip files but my IT manager assures me we have no restrictions and these settings have not been changed).  In doing so, I had to install Azure functions core tools from scratch as it had never been installed on that machine before.
- Creating a completely new clean functionapp and deploying there.
- Creating a brand new minimal Python application in a clean directory and deploying this to the new functionapp.

I get the same message in each case.

I'm stuck here.  Does anyone have any more information about what the error message might mean is going wrong or any ideas?

Other investigations -

- I've tried deploying as a different Azure user (same error).
- I've checked for any processes using port 9091 (none were found).

I have also tried to build locally using `func azure functionapp publish IncidentProcessing4 --build local`

I got some different error messages

```
Performing local build for functions project.
Directory .python_packages already in sync with requirements.txt. Skipping restoring dependencies...
Uploading package...
Uploading 0 B [###################################################################################]
Attempted to divide by zero.
Retry: 1 of 3
Uploading 0 B [###################################################################################]
Attempted to divide by zero.
Retry: 2 of 3
Uploading 0 B [###################################################################################]
Attempted to divide by zero.
Retry: 3 of 3
Uploading 0 B [###################################################################################]
Attempted to divide by zero.
```

I noticed that in my \users\name\appdata\local\temp directory 2 files had been created by the build, called temp374D.tmp and tmp374E.tmp.  The first of these was 0KB in size and the 2nd 8KB in size.

My suspicion is something is causing the first file to be created and something on the server is attempting and failing to unzip it.

More additional information - "Deploy to Function App" from Visual Studio code deploys, but when the Azure function runs, I get errors about modules referenced by the function not being loaded.    If it's possible to deploy the modules in requirements.txt with the function app that will be a work around.

Comment: I was deploying through the vs code plugin, for me I found the 7-13-2023 version was bugged and didn't work. Probably the similar bug mentioned below where a space in the function name folder or something like that causes issues. Downgrading to one version prior worked.

Answer (score 3):

This may not apply, given your exhaustive set of things you did trying to diagnose the issue, but I'll throw it out there. I have run into this if my function is running, either in a terminal window (via `func host start`) or even via the VSCode functions extension.

It would seem like it should be obvious to see if anything's running, but I've seen VSCode leave behind function host processes in a running state. To check, you could check netstat (`netstat -a -n | grep 9091`) or lsof (`lsof -nP -iTCP:9091 | grep LISTEN`). The latter gives you the pid that has the port open.

Comment: Thanks for this. Unfortunately there wasn't any process running that listened on port 9091.  I've also tried deploying from a different Azure user account in case anything had been corrupted with the permissions of my account without success.

Comment: This worked for me when deploying from Windows 11. Absurd.

Answer (score 3):

I think I've fixed it by reverting to an earlier version of Azure Functions Core Tools.  It's deploying with 2.7.1575.

I'll experiment to see if I can find out any more but I've got my function deploying now.

Comment: It seems to have broken between builds  2.7.1948 and 2.7.2100

Comment: I am facing the same issue. No luck yet.

Comment: How can I install the specific version of function core tool?

Comment: 1) Uninstall first: npm -g uninstall azure-functions-core-tools; 2) Install specific version: npm -g install azure-functions-core-tools@2.7.1575

Comment: To install specific version: npm -g install azure-functions-core-tools@2.7.1948 For me this fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that there was a bug introduced in Azure Functions Core Tools such that if your function directory full path had a space character in it Eg- `/home/my functions project/`, it would create a zip package with 0 bytes.

See - https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/issues/1867

This will be fixed in the next release. In the meanwhile, anyone experiencing this can mitigate the problem if they switch their function project to be in a path without space characters.

Sorry about that!

Answer (score 0):

I am using core-tools version 3 and the same problem exists there as well. As Ankit mentioned in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61380640/2502554), the issue occurs when there's a space in the project path.

One solution to this could be to move your project to another path without spaces until the next release fixes the issue but this is not always feasible/desirable. Instead we can create a shortcut (aka junctions on windows systems) to the original folder in a new path without spaces. So here's a batch file snippet which uses junctions for publishing functions to Azure till next release.

```
:: login and create resources with cli
....

:: enter into a path of choice without spaces (eg. my Windows Temp folder path has no spaces)
pushd %PATH_WITHOUT_SPACES%

:: create a junction to project path here and navigate to it
mklink /J tmpdir %PROJECT_PATH_WITH_SPACES%
pushd tmpdir

:: execute publish as you would normally. It will succeed now!
call func azure functionapp publish %APP_NAME%

:: cleanup and return to old working dir
popd
rmdir tmpdir
popd
```